# How to check/uncheck all checkboxes with Jquery and use .change() function on each checkbox to update database?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form that contains checkboxes.  When each checkbox is checked or unchecked, it executes a `.change` function which calls a `.post` function.  This `.post` function kicks off a PHP script that updates a database that either sets a status to a 1 (checked) or 0 (unchecked).

This works fine when I am checking or unchecking each checkbox one by one, but when I try to use a check/uncheck-all jquery function which checks or unchecks each of these checkboxes all at once, it seems as though the `.change` function does not get processed for each changed checkbox and the database is not updated.

Here's the code that "listens" for the .change:

```
    $('.location_check').change( function () {

        // If the checkbox has been changed to "checked", then run the job to set the db to 1 for that row
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var $report_f = $(this).attr("name");
            $.post('processes/updateLocationReportFlag.php', { record: $report_f, value: 1 });
        }

        // If the checkbox has been changed to "not checked", then run the job to set the db to 0 for that row
        if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
            var $report_f = $(this).attr("name");
            $.post('processes/updateLocationReportFlag.php', { record: $report_f, value: 0 });
        }

    });
```

Here's the code I'm using to check/uncheck all:

```
    $('#location_checkall').click( function () {

            $(this).parents('#locations_frame').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).parents('#locations_frame').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked).change();
```

...although, it would probably be wise to add a server-side script to handle multiple checkbox values at once. Many browsers have limits on the number of connections that can be opened at a time and if you have many checkboxes, you may run into this limit, with unexpected and undesirable results.

You may also want to look into JQuery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function to improve performance. It allows you to have a single event handler to which the event is 'delegated' rather than one per DOM element.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked.  This is a great short-term fix to keep me moving on this prototype.  However, I am going to take your advice on processing this on the server-side after this stage of development is behind me.